# SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY not returning the last column properly

Tags: php

How come the last column during my `SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY` does not appear? Everything else on my page is properly displaying and I can even `ECHO $row[7]` at any point after the $stmt execution to show the right info.

If I echo a duplicate statement of `$row[7]` then the column will successfully appear 1/2 times. Which makes absolutely no sense to me. Why would 1 column be invisible while the other perfectly appears with the same line of code.

What I'm basically trying to say is I can achieve my desired result by writing in `$row[7]` call twice in my loop, but that's an extremely dirty solution. I want to do it properly

```
<?php
/* Link DB */
include_once '../config.php';

/* Initialize Connection */
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conn_array);
if ($conn){
}else{
    die; 
}

/* Prepare Statement Preparation */
$sql = "
Select C.AccountID, C.AccountName, C.CharacterID, C.CharacterName, Jobcode, convert(varchar(25), LastLoginDate, 120) as LastLoginDate, Coin, WarehouseCoin
From Characters as C
INNER JOIN CharacterStatus AS CS
ON C.CharacterID = CS.CharacterID and C.CharacterName is NOT NULL
Where CharacterName = ?
";

/* Assign Parameter values. */
$myparams['accountname'] = $_POST['accountname'];

// Array requirement for prepare statement.
$procedure_params = array(
    array(&$myparams['accountname'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

/* Prepare the statement. */
if( $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $procedure_params))
{
    //  echo "Statement prepared.\n";
} 
else
{
    //  echo "Statement could not be prepared.\n";
    //  ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}

/* Execute the statement. */
if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt))
{
    // echo "Statement executed.\n";
    // ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}
else
{
     // echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";
     // ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}

echo

'
<tr>
<th>Account ID</th>
<th>Account</th>
<th>Character ID</th>
<th>Character</th>
<th>Specialization</th>
<th>Last Login</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Storaged Gold</th>
</tr>';

/* ID # to increment itself. I.E 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.. */
while ($rows=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
echo 
'
<tr>
<td> '.$rows[0].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[1].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[2].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[3].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[4].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[5].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[6].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[7].' </td>
</tr>
';  

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Tried replacing the rows[7] with any of the others in the array and still didn't work

Comment: Can you try to add this code `print_r($rows);` in the while loop and let me know what you will the output form this function

Comment: It actually detected the $rows[7] even though it is invisible on the page for me.

Comment: Still lookin for help

Comment: Please show the result of the `print_r($rows)` in the while loop by the screenshot. So I can sure which thing is returned.